# Java: Getting dynamic information from array list for making decisions

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have a text input file that looks like this:

```
011,AgeOfEmpires,RTS,156
022,Oblivion,RPG,88
033,CallOfDuty,FPS,2
044,Halo,FPS,1
```

(Format is ID, name, genre, copies sold)

The information is read with Scanner and placed into an array list. Code is here:

```
File temp = new File("file.txt");
        Scanner file = new Scanner(temp);

        List<Game> games = new ArrayList<Game>();

    while(file.hasNextLine())
    {
      String data = file.nextLine();
      String[] details = data.split(",");
      String number = details[0];
      String name = details[1];
      String genre = details[2];
      int price = Integer.parseInt(details[3]);
      Game g = new Game(number, name, genre, price);
      games.add(g);
    }
```

(Also note in my program I have a class with getters and setters to be able to fetch the information in the array)

The problem is that I don't know how to compare the data for certain decisions.

For example, say the program will give a message if the a genre sells more than 100 copies. My intuition says that I would program something like this:

`If (soldRTS > 100) System.out.println("RTS games are popular lately");`

However, that can't work because the value for the genres are going to be "dynamic" or "variable" (not really sure how to call it). That is, the author of the input file could have any sort of genre, and all their sales will be different.

I somehow need to "dynamically" handle the information in the array list for these decisions. I *know* there has to be some way to do this but I really can't find out how. I know it has to be online somewhere but since I don't know what this process is even called I am having trouble searching for it. Could someone please explain how this is done, or at least point me in the right direction?

Thank you so much, and if you need more of the code I can edit this post. I think everything needed is already included.

Comment: You have two options: use a database, or parse the text file then search linearly for any query. Both are valid depending on your requirements. Is your question specifically about how to parse the file to get the data into a meaningful format?

Comment: A simple way would be just to loop through the List after you have loaded the data, outputting whatever information you want.

Comment: By the way, consider what happens when the game name contains a comma...

Comment: The text file is required to not contain commas and must always be in format ID, name, genre, copies sold. I can only read the text file once so searching the text is a no-no. I must search the array list or whatever I stored the text file into.
I do know how to loop through the list. For example, I can make the program output the total or details[3] which will give the total sales of *everything*. The problem is I need to be able to differentiate from sales or RPG, RTS, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarized, your problem is that you need a way to, for any given arbitrary genre, track the count, and you only know how to do it if you know the genres in advance. Try a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). More specifically, a `Map<String, Integer>`. In most cases when using a `Map` the implementation class you want is probably [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

The keys in this map would be the genres, and the values would be the total sales for the genre. For each game, first check whether the map `containsKey()` the genre; if it does, `get()` the count so far, add the current game's sales, and `put()` the new value back in; if it doesn't, just `put()` the current game's sales number because it's the first for that genre.

When you've done this for all the games, you can go through the whole list of all genres and their sales counts by using the map's `entrySet()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I did some quick reading/video on HashMaps and from what I understand, before I can check to see if it `containsKey()` will work, I have to populate the map with a list of genres, right?  So to put it in...well that I can't quite figure out. Do I have to loop through the list and do something like `mapRisk.put(getRisk())`? Something like that?

Comment: @javacplusplus No, that's incorrect. `containsKey()` works whether you've populated the map or not, and in fact exists specifically as a way to check whether the map has been populated yet. On a brand new empty map, `containsKey()` returns `false` for everything. Each time you `put()` something into the map, `containsKey()` will start returning `true` for that key.